# Importing from parent directory gets error

Tags: python

The project structure on my local machine is setup like this:

```
python/
    __init__.py
    readText.py
    testing/
        __init__.py
        removeDuplicates.py
```

In removeDuplicates.py I am trying to import as follows:

```
from python import readText
```

This gives: ImportError: No module name 'python'

My **init**.py in both folders are blank by the way.

Comment: How is python supposed to find that module? Try `from .. import readText`.

Comment: I tried that as well but it gives me this error: SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the parent directory of your `python` subdirectory to be present in `sys.path`.  If you execute your script from that directory, the import should work.  But the easiest way to do this is to export the environment variable PYTHONPATH.

Comment: How do I add something to sys.path? Is that something I need to change in Python or on the operating system?

Comment: On the operating system.  It's about the environment.  You should execute in the shell that you will run your code in, `export PYTHONPATH=/path/of/the/parentdir/`

Comment: Is that something I can put into the __init__.py so that it does that automatically, without having to set the path each time?

Comment: Short answer: no.  Long answer: it is actually possible to munge sys.path from within the python runtime, but that's barking up the wrong tree.  don't do that.

Comment: Ah crap, yea I just tried that by doing: import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/package_or_module"). I'm using Windows by the way, so looks like I need to use 'set' rather than export?

Comment: you can actually use `import os` and than 
`os.sys.path.append( os.path.dirname( os.path.dirname( os.path.abspath(__file__))))` before you `from python import readText`. This will add the parent dir to the system path on runtime.

Comment: Yes I was assuming linux, use `set` instead of `export` on windows.  If you munge the sys.path from within python code, you are a bad person and you should feel bad.

Comment: lol yea... I ended up moving the file so they are all in one directory to avoid the issue. I'll click the check since you pointed me in the right direction. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You want to import something from the parent directory, use

```
from .. import readText
```

see relative imports:

https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-328.html

Comment: This will not work because 1)  the parent module can not be loaded, as described in the question  2) it should be 2 dots, not 3

Comment: you are right, the correct answer is my previous comment.

Comment: It's still not a useful answer though.  All you have done is swapped a broken absolute import for a broken relative import.  The fact that the import wasn't working is unrelated to whether it is relative or absolute.

Comment: but it think OP wants to import this file in the parent directory, I think adding the module python to sys.path is not necessary. If one wants to import something from the same module use relative import, if you want from another module use absolute. I'm no expert please explain why you think otherwise.

Comment: Because it just doesn't work like that.  You will get the error that OP has already mentioned on his comment on the question (SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import)